# How to retrieve the xml messages from cordys

Tags: cordys-opentext

I am trying to find a way to get the xml contents of a cordys request and use some tool to retry.

The cordys PIM is able to show the XML messages for debugging, hence it will be getting stored somewhere.

Can someone help in figuring out the location or point to any APIs that can get this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the message map XML (and other process details) using the 'GetProcessInstances' web service. An example call would be:

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Body>
        <GetProcessInstances xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/pim/queryinstancedata/1.0">
            <Query xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/cql/1.0">
                <Select>
                    <QueryableObject>PROCESS_INSTANCE</QueryableObject>
                    <Field>INSTANCE_ID</Field>
                    <Field>STATUS</Field>
                    <Field>PROCESS_TYPE</Field>
                    <Field>MESSAGE_MAP</Field>
                </Select>
                <Filters>
                    <EQ field="INSTANCE_ID">
                        <Value>0AF55918-C0A5-11E5-F1C1-6CBB1087F12D</Value>
                    </EQ>
                </Filters>
                <Cursor numRows="50"/>
            </Query>
        </GetProcessInstances>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

More information about this web service can be found on the Cordys wiki: https://wiki.cordys.com/display/otc106/GetProcessInstances